# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor':

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, autowired

BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType

getting following error:

```
    ... 12 more
2015-07-06 23:03:06 [main] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:512 - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@105fece7: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,baseSpringConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.openrepose.dbutil.spring.config.DbUtilsSpringConfig,sessionFactory,dataSource,hibernateUtil,hibernateUtils,org.openrepose.dao.model.spring.config.DaoSpringConfig,clientAuthConfigDao,ipIdentityConfigDao,rackspaceAuthorizationDao,quotaDao,rateLimitingConfigurationDao,systemModelDao,rackspaceAuthorizationConverter,ipIdentityConfigConverter,quotaConverter,rateLimitingConfigurationBase,clientAuthConfigConverter,rateLimitingConfigurationConverter,systemModelConverter,systemModelBase,quotaBase,ipIdentityConfigBase,clientAuthConfigBase,rackspaceAuthorizationBase]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.openrepose.base.test.TestManagerBase.main(TestManagerBase.java:71)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethodIfAvailable(ClassUtils.java:668)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<clinit>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    ... 12 more
```

Scenario: 
i've mutli module project. 
 
model : hibernate entity 
dbutils : hibernate session factory injection has model as dependency 
 
dao : dao related operation along with autowire of hibernate has dbutils as  dependency 
 
base : have dao as depedency and has same classes as in model without annotation (business object).

I used java based configuration for autowiring. 
For autowiring for dbutils

```
package org.openrepose.dbutil.spring.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.openrepose.dbutil.constants.DbUtilsSpringConfigConstants;
import org.openrepose.dbutil.dbconnection.HibernateUtils;
import org.openrepose.dbutil.hibernateutil.HibernateUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;

/**
 * Spring IoC configuration. This class is responsible for building session
 * factory, hibernate util autowire and hibernateutils autowire
 * 
 * @author Nitin gupta (gupta.nitin@snapdeal.com)
 *
 */
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.openrepose.dbutil" })
public class DbUtilsSpringConfig {

    // autowire environment, properties read form
    // classpath:persistence-mysql.properties
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Build a session factory
     * 
     * @param dataSource
     * @return
     */
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DbUtilsSpringConfigConstants.DB_SESSION_FACTORY)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("org.openrepose.entities");
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();

    }

    /**
     * Get The Data Source. Configure all Db related configuration here
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = DbUtilsSpringConfigConstants.DB_DATA_SOURCE)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * get hibernate properties. Configure all hibernate related configuration
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -4496310006095041101L;

            {

                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"));

                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

                setProperty("hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer ",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer"));

                setProperty("cache.provider_class", env.getProperty("cache.provider_class"));

                setProperty("current_session_context_class", env.getProperty("current_session_context_class"));

                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"));
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * For autowiring Hibernateutil object. Pattern: By constructor
     * 
     * @param sessionFactory
     * @return
     */
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DbUtilsSpringConfigConstants.DB_HIBERNATE_UTIL)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public HibernateUtil getHibernateUtil(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateUtil(sessionFactory);
    }

    /**
     * For autowiring Hibernateutils object. Pattern: By constructor
     * 
     * @param util
     * @return
     */
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DbUtilsSpringConfigConstants.DB_HIBERNATE_UTILS)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public HibernateUtils getHibernateUtils(HibernateUtil util) {
        return new HibernateUtils(util);
    }

}
```

for Dao autowiring

```
package org.openrepose.dao.model.spring.config;

import org.openrepose.dao.model.constants.DaoSpringConfigConstants;
import org.openrepose.dao.model.implementation.clientauthentication.ClientAuthDAO;
import org.openrepose.dao.model.implementation.clientauthorization.ClientAuthorizationDAO;
import org.openrepose.dao.model.implementation.ipidentity.IpIdentityDAO;
import org.openrepose.dao.model.implementation.quota.QuotaDAO;
import org.openrepose.dao.model.implementation.ratelimit.RatelimitDAO;
import org.openrepose.dao.model.implementation.systemmodel.SystemModelDAO;
import org.openrepose.dao.model.interfaces.IModelDao;
import org.openrepose.dbutil.spring.config.DbUtilsSpringConfig;
import org.openrepose.entities.clientauthentication.ClientAuthConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.clientauthorization.RackspaceAuthorizationConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.ipidentity.IpIdentityConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.quota.QuotaLimitsConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.ratelimit.RateLimitConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.systemmodel.SystemModelConfigEO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

/**
 * Spring IoC configuration. This class is responsible for autowiring the all
 * service exposed by Dao layer
 * 
 * @author Nitin gupta (gupta.nitin@snapdeal.com)
 *
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "org.openrepose.dao" })
@Import(DbUtilsSpringConfig.class)
public class DaoSpringConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DaoSpringConfigConstants.DAO_CLIENT_AUTH)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelDao<ClientAuthConfigEO> getClientAuth() {
        return new ClientAuthDAO();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DaoSpringConfigConstants.DAO_IP_IDENTITY)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelDao<IpIdentityConfigEO> getIpIdentity() {
        return new IpIdentityDAO();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DaoSpringConfigConstants.DAO_RATE_LIMIT)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelDao<RateLimitConfigEO> getRateLimit() {
        return new RatelimitDAO();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DaoSpringConfigConstants.DAO_SYSTEM_MODEL)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelDao<SystemModelConfigEO> getSystemModel() {
        return new SystemModelDAO();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DaoSpringConfigConstants.DAO_CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelDao<RackspaceAuthorizationConfigEO> getClientAuthorization() {
        return new ClientAuthorizationDAO();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = DaoSpringConfigConstants.DAO_QUOTA)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelDao<QuotaLimitsConfigEO> getQuotaLimits() {
        return new QuotaDAO();
    }

}
```

and for base autowiring

```
package org.openrepose.base.spring.config;

import org.openrepose.base.bos.constants.BaseSpringConfigConstants;
import org.openrepose.base.clientauthentication.bos.ClientAuthConfig;
import org.openrepose.base.clientauthentication.service.implementation.ClientAuthBaseImpl;
import org.openrepose.base.clientauthorization.bos.RackspaceAuthorization;
import org.openrepose.base.clientauthorization.service.implementation.ClientAuthorizationBaseImpl;
import org.openrepose.base.conversion.utility.IObjectConverter;
import org.openrepose.base.interfaces.IModelBase;
import org.openrepose.base.ipidentity.bos.IpIdentityConfig;
import org.openrepose.base.ipidentity.service.implementation.IpIdentityBaseImpl;
import org.openrepose.base.quota.bos.Limits;
import org.openrepose.base.quota.service.implementation.QuotaBaseImpl;
import org.openrepose.base.ratelimit.bos.RateLimitingConfiguration;
import org.openrepose.base.ratelimit.service.implementation.RateLimitBaseImpl;
import org.openrepose.base.systemmodel.bos.SystemModel;
import org.openrepose.base.systemmodel.service.implementation.SystemModelBaseImpl;
import org.openrepose.dao.model.spring.config.DaoSpringConfig;
import org.openrepose.entities.clientauthentication.ClientAuthConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.clientauthorization.RackspaceAuthorizationConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.ipidentity.IpIdentityConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.quota.QuotaLimitsConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.ratelimit.RateLimitConfigEO;
import org.openrepose.entities.systemmodel.SystemModelConfigEO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

/**
 * Spring IoC configuration. This class is responsible for autowiring the all
 * service exposed by Base layer
 * 
 * @author Nitin gupta (gupta.nitin@snapdeal.com)
 *
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "org.openrepose.base" })
@Import({DaoSpringConfig.class} )
public class BaseSpringConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.OBJECT_CONVERTER_CLIENT_AUTH)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IObjectConverter<ClientAuthConfig, ClientAuthConfigEO> getClientAuthConverter() {
        return new ClientAuthConfig();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.OBJECT_CONVERTER_CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IObjectConverter<RackspaceAuthorization, RackspaceAuthorizationConfigEO> getRackspaceAuthorizationConverter() {
        return new RackspaceAuthorization();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.OBJECT_CONVERTER_IP_IDENTITY)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IObjectConverter<IpIdentityConfig, IpIdentityConfigEO> getIpIdentityConverter() {
        return new IpIdentityConfig();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.OBJECT_CONVERTER_QUOTA)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IObjectConverter<Limits, QuotaLimitsConfigEO> getQuotaConverter() {
        return new Limits();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.OBJECT_CONVERTER_RATE_LIMIT)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IObjectConverter<RateLimitingConfiguration, RateLimitConfigEO> getRateLimitConverter() {
        return new RateLimitingConfiguration();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.OBJECT_CONVERTER_SYSTEM_MODEL)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IObjectConverter<SystemModel, SystemModelConfigEO> getSystemModelConverter() {
        return new SystemModel();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.BASE_SYSTEM_MODEL)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelBase<SystemModel> getSystemModelBase() {
        return new SystemModelBaseImpl();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.BASE_RATE_LIMIT)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelBase<RateLimitingConfiguration> getRateLimitBase() {
        return new RateLimitBaseImpl();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.BASE_QUOTA)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelBase<Limits> getLimitsBase() {
        return new QuotaBaseImpl();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.BASE_IP_IDENTITY)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelBase<IpIdentityConfig> getIpIdentityConfigBase() {
        return new IpIdentityBaseImpl();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.BASE_CLIENT_AUTH)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelBase<ClientAuthConfig> getClientAuthBase() {
        return new ClientAuthBaseImpl();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = BaseSpringConfigConstants.BASE_CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public IModelBase<RackspaceAuthorization> getRackspaceAuthorizationBase() {
        return new ClientAuthorizationBaseImpl();
    }

}
```

Now i'm trying to test does these autowiring works or not.
I checked upto Daos layer it works using below code

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DaoSpringConfig.class);
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    IModelDao<ClientAuthConfigEO> c = (IModelDao<ClientAuthConfigEO>) context
            .getBean(DaoSpringConfigConstants.DAO_CLIENT_AUTH);
```

BUT WHEN I'M TRYING TO DO SAME AT BASE CLASS IT DOES NOT WORK (USING BELOW CODE)

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
AbstractApplicationContext context1 = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BaseSpringConfig.class);
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
IObjectConverter<SystemModel, SystemModelConfigEO> c2 = (IObjectConverter<SystemModel, SystemModelConfigEO>) context1
        .getBean(BaseSpringConfigConstants.OBJECT_CONVERTER_SYSTEM_MODEL);
```

EVEN If i try to put same code used in dao layer in base layer .. it does not work throws above exception.

Please help, i really need to fix it

Base Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
        <artifactId>profile-support</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>repose-config-base</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- logs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
            <artifactId>repose-config-models</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
            <artifactId>repose-config-daos</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
            <artifactId>repose-config-catalog</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are possible two reasons as per my understanding

1. One such scenario I faced in the past due to the jar files. In my case was the javaee files.
   The problem is with javaee.jar file. The recommended way is always get the original full version of javaee.jar file from the http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html Kindly download and install the J2EE SDK, and the javaee.jar can be found in the “\J2EE_SDK_FOLDER\lib” folder. Include it into your local Maven repository or project classpath. Hence here also could be a similar problem.
2. The other possible scenario could be that files are not getting scanned hence something wrong with the component scan

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input. But this is not due to javaee jar. I've tried including this jar too. nothing works

Answer (score 0):

In my case, higher version was needed. If you've moved to Java 8 from 6 then this should work.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
 </dependency>
```